# How do the trains run!

Tags: phrase-meaning

In "Dr. Thorndyke's Case-Book" by Austin Freeman", ِDr. Gervis was talking to his friend, saying:

"I think I had better run up to town and confer with Thorndyke," said I. "**How do the trains run**?"

"There is **a good train** in about three-quarters of an hour," replied Foxton.

I think that he meant to ask him "**how fast trains are**?"

And the other meant to say "**there is a fast train**".

Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question "How do the trains run?", in context, means "What are the train schedules?" or "When will there be trains available?", with the same meaning: "When can I get one?".

The statement "There is a good train in about three-quarters of an hour." means that that will be a suitable train for getting to the questioner's destination.

What would make a train "good"? Maybe it would be a good choice because there would be less stops along the way, or maybe it would go the full distance without any transfers.